# Как вывести в ListView выбранную в GridControl строку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Делаю вывод с текстового файла в `GridControl`, далее нужно если в `GridControl` выбрали строку, то вывести ее содержимое в `ListView` [image]

```
<dxg:GridControl AutoGenerateColumns="AddNew" EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" x:Name="myGridControl" Margin="0,0,231,0">

    <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Time Data"  FieldName="TimeData" />
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Classa"     FieldName="DataClasa" />
        <dxg:GridColumn Header="Co to jest" FieldName="Discription"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

    <dxg:GridControl.View>
        <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" ShowTotalSummary="True"/>
    </dxg:GridControl.View>
</dxg:GridControl>
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="229" Margin="549,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял твою задачу. Ты выделяешь строку в Grid и эта-же строка у тебя должна отобразиться в ListView?

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource someDataSource}">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" x:Name="someGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SM}"></DataGrid>
<ListView Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=someGrid, Path=SelectedItems}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView> 
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Objective}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Header2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Distances[0]}"/>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: да, но я уже сделал, просто забыл забрать вопрос

Comment: @momo Тебе надо было самому на него ответить или удалить, что бы не висел тут не отвеченным.

Comment: @momo поставь галочку под своим или моим ответом, что бы вопрос не висел не отвеченным.

Answer (score 1):

вот ответ

```
        <dxg:GridControl EnableSmartColumnsGeneration="True" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding View}" 
                     x:Name="myGridControl"  
                     Margin="0,0,3,0"  
                     SelectionMode="Row" Grid.RowSpan="5">

        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Type" FieldName="TypeFiles" Width="30"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Time Data"  FieldName="TimeData" SortMode="DisplayText" SortOrder="Ascending" Width="50"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Classa"     FieldName="DataClasa" Width="60"/>
            <dxg:GridColumn Header="Co to jest"  FieldName="Discription" />
        </dxg:GridControl.Columns>

        <dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem FieldName="TimeData" SummaryType="Count"/>
            <dxg:GridSummaryItem SummaryType="Count" Alignment="Right"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.TotalSummary>

        <dxg:GridControl.View>
            <dxg:TableView AllowPerPixelScrolling="True" 
                           ShowFixedTotalSummary="True" 
                           UseEvenRowBackground="True" 
                           AllowEditing="False" 
                           NavigationStyle="Row" AutoWidth="True"/>
        </dxg:GridControl.View>
    </dxg:GridControl>

    <dxe:TextEdit 
                  x:Name="MyText" 
                  PrintTextWrapping="NoWrap"
                  TextWrapping="Wrap"                       
                  TextTrimming="None" Grid.Column="1"
                  Text="{Binding ElementName=myGridControl, Path=SelectedItem.Discription, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="4"/>
```